# Excel AutoFilter Criteria Variant to string

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm trying to get an AutoFilter setting as a string.

I set `A1:A5` in a worksheet to:

```
Rows
valA
valB
valC
valD
```

Then I AutoFilter the worksheet and select `Rows` values `valA`, `valB`, `valC`.  (I.e., I have filtered out `Rows` value `valD`.)

I run the following VBA:

```
Sub CaptureFilters()
    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(1)
        Cells(1, 3).Value = Join(.Criteria1)
        Cells(1, 4).Value = Replace(Join(.Criteria1), "@=", "")
    End With
End Sub
```

Now both worksheet cells `C1` and `D1` give a `#NAME?` error, but their formulas show `=@valA =@valB =@valC`.

VBA shows that `.Criteria1` is an Array of `Variant/String`s.
[image: Excel VBA inspection]

How can I get `.Criteria1` as a string value in a worksheet cell?  In this example I want a cell that contains the string `valA valB valC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite to

```
Sub CaptureFilters()
    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(1)
        Cells(1, 3).Value2 = "'" & Join(.Criteria1)
        Cells(1, 4).Value = "'" & Replace(Join(.Criteria1), "@=", "")
    End With
End Sub
```

Otherwise Excel will interpret the string as formula as it starts with a `=`.

Or you try

```
Sub CaptureFiltersA()
    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(1)
        Cells(1, 3).Value2 = Replace(Join(.Criteria1), "=", " ")
        Cells(1, 4).Value = Replace(Join(.Criteria1), "=", "")
    End With
End Sub
```

---

There are four scenarios for a text autofilter – one value, two, and more than two. To handle them all:

```
Sub CaptureFiltersA()
    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(1)
        If IsArray(.Criteria1) Then  ' CASE: More than two values
            Cells(1, 3).Value = Replace(Join(.Criteria1, ","), "=", "")
        Else
            Cells(1, 3).Value = Replace(.Criteria1, "=", "")  ' CASE: One value
            If .Count = 2 Then  ' CASE: Two values
                Cells(1, 3).Value = Cells(1, 3).Value + "," + Replace(.Criteria2, "=", "")
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```